# Put JSON datas from database to html

Tags: php, javascript, html, json

In order to retrieve all my database, I have made a simple php/mysql request and encoded it to json.

I now have this :

```
[
   {
      "id":"1",
      "title":"Paris - New York",
      "desc":awesome food,
      "price":"5-10",
      "adress":"63 Rue du faubourg Saint-Denis",
      "map":"https:\/\/maps.google.com\/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=fr&geocode=&q=80+Rue+du+Faubourg+Saint-Denis,+Paris,+France&aq=0&oq=80+rue+du+faubour&sll=37.0625,-95.677068&sspn=36.778911,79.013672&t=m&ie=UTF8&hq=&hnear=80+Rue+du+Faubourg+Saint-Denis,+75010+Paris,+%C3%8Ele-de-France,+France&ll=48.873562,2.35491&spn=0.001866,0.004823&z=14&output=embed",
      "background":"pny.jpg"
   },
   {
      "id":"2",
      "title":"Urfam Durum",
      "desc":"des sandwichs Kurdes vraiment bons",
      "price":"5-10",
      "adress":"66 rue du faubourg Saint-Denis",
      "map":"google blabla",
      "background":"ud.jpg"
   }
]
```

I want to randomly display a single post in my differents DIV by injecting it by javascript/jquery (with something like $('').html())

I'm expecting a result like this :

```
<div class="span6 offset3 place">
      <h2>**"title":"Paris - New York"**</h2>

      <ul class="infos">
        <li class="prix">**"price":"5-10"**</li>
        <li class="adresse"><a href="#map" data-toggle="modal">**"adress":"63 Rue du faubourg Saint-Denis"**</a></li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

Texts between (**) means where I want my datas to be displayed

I think you have the idea ! Any help would be really appreciated

PS : English, is not my mother tongue, so please forgive my mistakes

Comment: Mustache templates would be a great solution for this. http://mustache.github.io/

Comment: How about returning the whole result as html? Since you are displaying a whole section of a page, return a html response and place in there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
  use JSON.parse() for parsing your json encoded data.


   $.ajax({ 
    url:"something.php",
    type:"POST",
    data:{data_You_send},
    success:function(data){

//this is your response that you retrieve

    var obj=JSON.parse(data)  //since the data that we have retrieved is in json_decoded format,we need to parse it

for(var i in obj){//to see all your data,try this for all fields
    console.log(obj[i].id+","+obj[i].title);//just for 2 fields for understanding purpose

$("#id").html(obj[0].id) or $("#id").text(obj[0].id)//assign innerHTML or content to respective elements by these jquery methods.
    }
```

Feel free to ask if any queries!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the underscore library with the template engine (_template). So you can pass the whole object and use the properties inside the template.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use jquery templates [github link](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jquery-tmpl)

also you can use

```
jQuery.each(json, function(i, v) {
    $('#containerDiv').append('<div class="span6 offset3 place"><h2>'+v.title+'</h2> <ul class="infos"><li class="prix">'+v.price+'</li> <li class="adresse"><a href="#map" data-toggle="modal">'+v.adress+'</a></li></ul></div>');
});
```

json in each loop it's your data

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var json = [{
            "id": "1",
            "title": "Paris - New York",
            "price": "5-10",
            "adress": "63 Rue du faubourg Saint-Denis",
            "map": "https:\/\/maps.google.com\/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=fr&geocode=&q=80+Rue+du+Faubourg+Saint-Denis,+Paris,+France&aq=0&oq=80+rue+du+faubour&sll=37.0625,-95.677068&sspn=36.778911,79.013672&t=m&ie=UTF8&hq=&hnear=80+Rue+du+Faubourg+Saint-Denis,+75010+Paris,+%C3%8Ele-de-France,+France&ll=48.873562,2.35491&spn=0.001866,0.004823&z=14&output=embed",
            "background": "pny.jpg"
        }];
    //Select the DOM objects and assign text values.
    $('.place h2').text(json[0].title);
    $('.prix').text(json[0].price);
    $('.adresse a').text(json[0].adress);
});
```

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/LBWXg/)

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using something like jquery to retrieve the data into the web page.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "get_json_data.php",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
        // *** Do things here with the data ***
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(error){
         alert("Something is wrong :" + error);
    }
});
```

You will have to ensure your php is sending JSON data.

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo $my_json_results;
```

Look at this post to see how you can use a template with your returned results :
[How do I use jquery templates with JSON data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6508902/how-do-i-use-jquery-templates-with-json-data)

Comment: I'm not pedantic about being downvoted, but I feel my response addresses the question. If you are downvoting but not saying why, you are not contributing to this community, and your input has a negative effect.