# AJAX - JS - Create a table from a AJAX response and put inside a <div>

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax

In this method I pass the response of this action in text form, but I would like to use the table format, how would I do it?

```
function loadAditivos(){
    $('#aditivoAbertoInformacoesTexto').html('<div id="loaderMaiorDemandante"></div>');
    $("#loader").show();
    var jsonHide = $('#activeJsonHide').html();
    if(jsonHide) {
        $.ajax({
              url: 'search.action', // action to be perform
              type: 'POST',       //type of posting the data
              data: { dataJson: jsonHide }, // data to set to Action Class
              dataType: 'text',
              success: function (html) {
                  $("#loader").hide();
                  $('#showAdditiveasText').html(html); //How to pass a tablw to That DIV?
              },

        });
    }
}
```

How could I pass this data to the div: "$('#showAdditiveasText').html(html)" using a table format?

Example:

```
[
  {
    "UserID": 1,
    "UserName": "rooter",
    "Password": "12345",
    "Country": "UK",
    "Email": "sac@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "UserID": 2,
    "UserName": "binu",
    "Password": "123",
    "Country": "uk",
    "Email": "Binu@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "UserID": 3,
    "UserName": "cal",
    "Password": "123",
    "Country": "uk",
    "Email": "cal@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "UserID": 4,
    "UserName": "nera",
    "Password": "1234",
    "Country": "uk",
    "Email": "nera@gmail.com"
  }
]
```

Comment: It would be best if the server sent table HTML. Converting the HTML to a different format will be tricky.

Comment: There is no easy way to accomplish that without parsing the data out of the HTML. Do you have control over the backend which is returning the response? If so, you should alter the response on the backend. Otherwise, you are going to have to parse the data out of that response and build a table yourself.

Comment: Even better would be to return JSON. Then the client can format it any way it wants.

Comment: Yep, i can return a JSON, do you guys have any example with JSON return?

Comment: @Chris Yep i can change, put some example in the main post

Comment: Maybe something along the lines of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6508902/how-do-i-use-jquery-templates-with-json-data

Answer (score 2):

You can dynamically create a table and append it to an element like below:

```js
var indices = ["UserID", "UserName", "Password", "Country", "Email"]
var data = [
  {
    "UserID": 1,
    "UserName": "rooter",
    "Password": "12345",
    "Country": "UK",
    "Email": "sac@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "UserID": 2,
    "UserName": "binu",
    "Password": "123",
    "Country": "uk",
    "Email": "Binu@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "UserID": 3,
    "UserName": "cal",
    "Password": "123",
    "Country": "uk",
    "Email": "cal@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "UserID": 4,
    "UserName": "nera",
    "Password": "1234",
    "Country": "uk",
    "Email": "nera@gmail.com"
  }
];

var table = $("<table>")
var thead = $('<thead>')
for(const index of indices) {
    $('<th>'+index+'</th>').appendTo(thead)
}
thead.appendTo(table)

var tbody = $('<tbody>')
for(const item of data) {
    var tr = $('<tr>')
    for(const index of indices) {
        $('<td>'+item[index]+'</td>').appendTo(tr)
  }
    tr.appendTo(tbody)
}
tbody.appendTo(table)

table.appendTo('#showAdditiveasText')
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="showAdditiveasText"></div>
```

Comment: how can a pass the value when a i have a object like date? ex [
  {
    tipo: "O",
    numero: "001",
    data: { year: 2019, month: 4, day: 18 },
    prazo: 0,
    documento: "4600530888",
  },
];

Because im getting the undefined error when i pass the "data" atribute

Comment: can you give me more details? need to know where 'undefined error' occurs